# How to loop a regex.match or add a range to String.Contains()

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, passwords

I've built a password Generator:

```
Public Function PassGen()

    Dim pool As String = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxzyABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ+@*#%&/()?!$-"
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim result As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do Until i = 10
        result &= pool(rnd.Next(0, pool.Length))
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Return result

End Function
```

Now I'd like to check if the generated password contains a number, upper- and lowercase and special characters. If the generated password doesn't contain those 4 things, it should generate another password and check it again and so on.

I tried to loop a `Regex.Match`:

```
    Dim text As String = PassGen()

    Do Until Regex.Match(text, "^[0-9]$")

        text = PassGen()

    Loop
```

What didnt work as it wont let me loop a `regex.match()`.

I also tried it with `String.Contains()`. But as far as I know the Contains-method can only check for one string and not for a range or a type(like Integer).

Is there a possibility to check my password for those four string-ranges or do I have to modify my function that it has to use one of each?

Comment: Your regex is only checking for **one** digit. Yes it can check for all those _four string ranges_. Could you give some valid password samples ? What's the maximum length ?

Comment: `Do Until i = 10` Password length is always 10. A valid password would be: xE3)g21v%P

Comment: You can try using `Do Until System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(text, "(?s)^(?=.*\d)(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\W)")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one regex to check the password strength:

```
Do Until System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(text, "(?s)^(?=.*\d)(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\W)")
```

The `\W` matches all special characters other than letters, digits and `_`, thus you have a much wider scope with it than manually defining a character class like `[+@*#%&/()?!$-]`.

The `(?s)` is an inline singleline modifier to force `.` to match a newline, too. The `\d` matches a digit, the `\p{Ll}` matches a lowercase letter, and `\p{Lu}` matches an uppercase letter. The lookaheads `(?=...)` are executed one after another upon success. If one of them returns false, the whole match is failed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `LIKE` keyword in VB. The `LIKE` is like a mini-regex built in into VB.NET.

```
If text Like "*[A-Z]*" AndAlso text Like "*[a-z]*" AndAlso text Like "*[0-9]*" AndAlso text Like "*[+@*#%&/()?!$-]*" Then
    ' it is a valid password

Else
    ' password doesn't match required constraints... do whatever to regenerate it here... 

End If
```

Comment: Thanks for this additional input. I wasn't aware of this command and it will be helpful in the future for sure :)

Comment: Since not everyone reads my answers fully, I will add a comment here: `\W` matches *all* special symbols, and with `Like`, we can only define a few (those we remember).

Comment: Yes, but `LIKE` is a dozen times faster than Regex, because it doesn't use the Regex engine. I avoid Regex, where string manipulation functions or LIKE keyword suffices.